# SQL OpenJSON obtain label in select output

Tags: sql, json, sql-server

I'm using the OpenJSON function in SQL to import various JSON format files into SQL and can usually handle the variations in formats from various sources, however I've got an example where I can't reach a certain value.

Example JSON format file:

```
{
  "bob": {
    "user_type": "standard", 
    "user_enabled": "true", 
    "last_login": "2021-07-25"
  }, 
  "claire": {
    "user_type": "administrator", 
    "user_enabled": "true", 
    "last_login": "2021-09-17"
  }
}
```

One of the values I want to return as one of my columns is the user's name;
I believe it's called the *key* but not entirely sure, because when I execute the following having loaded the json string into the @json variable:

```
select *
from openjson(@json)
```

I get two columns, one labelled *key* containing the username, the other containing my nested json string within `{}` braces.

Usually, to run my select statement, I would do something like

```
select username,user_type,user_enabled,last_login
from openjson(@thisjson)
with (
    username nvarchar(100),
    user_type nvarchar(100),
    user_enabled nvarchar(100),
    last_login nvarchar(100)
)
```

I get that sometimes I have to put the base in the brackets after `openjson`, and sometimes I have to follow the input column definitions with something like `'$.last_login'` to help traverse the structure, but can't work out how to identify or select the placeholder for the username.

Comment: @lptr You should post that as an answer

Comment: @lptr perfect that works, if you post as an answer i'll mark it as accepted